# Div still has margin even with margin: 0;

Tags: html, css, layout, margin

I am trying to make a div with no margin around it (for a header across the page). I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        .test {
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test">&nbsp;</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but the div still has a margin around it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: don't forget to reset the padding as well. The correct answer have already been given by @bažmegakapa

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's the default margin around `body`. Browsers define certain default values for certain CSS properties on certain elements - this is one of them. Unfortunately sometimes the default values vary from browser to browser.

You should either use a so-called [Reset CSS](https://cssdeck.com/blog/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) or remove the default margin:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6WQHb/)

Answer (score 0):

The body has a margin too. So unless you set the margin 0 on the body, it won't set the margin to 0 for that page completely.